# Comando Java para somar coluna em tabela

Tags: java, android

Preciso do código em Java no Android para fazer a soma da coluna de uma determinada tabela SQLite.

Sei que o comando é "`Select sum(coluna) from tabela`", mas o que preciso saber é como escrever isso em Java para conseguir recuperar esse valor da soma.

Como a coluna se trata de números, algum comando que me retorne um valor inteiro que eu possa estar utilizando em outros lugares.
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: E a tag Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente você precisa acessar uma coluna da tabela, mas não consigo dizer exatamente que tipo de componente está utilizando, sendo assim, a minha melhor sugestão é utilizar o `EntityManager` da JPA.

Comece criando uma classe que abrirá a conexão ao banco, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
private static ConnectionFactory instance;
private final EntityManagerFactory factory;

private ConnectionFactory() {
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("nome da persistence unit"));
}

private EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return factory.createEntityManager();
}

public static EntityManager getConnection() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new ConnectionFactory();
    }

    return instance.getEntityManager();
}
```

Após isso, crie uma classe Entidade, que será a responsável por receber os dados recuperados da tabela por uma outra classe que acessa o banco, exemplo: "SomaDAO".

E finalmente crie a classe de acesso a dados e utilize uma `Query` para recuperar os dados da coluna da tabela que você deseja realizar a soma.

```
public Integer soma() {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT sum(coluna) from tabela");

    Integer soma = (Integer) q.getSingleResult();

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();

    return soma;
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Aqui o código para um comando SELECT no banco SQLite que pode ser utilizado em sistemas Android. Vide esta questão: [Android SQLite SELECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280692/android-sqlite-select-query)

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT sum(column1) FROM table ", null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
           //Recuperando valores 
           int column1 = c.getInt(0);

    //Fazendo algo com os valores

        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
```

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pela resposta. Mais não funciona o query no meu projeto java. Ele é para plataforma android, e os comandos sqlite acredito q sejam diferentes.

Comment: Adicionado parte de código que funciona no SQLite na resposta.